# Borel measurable vs continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, borel-measures

I have the following statement which I think (given the definitions below) should hold. I would appreciate your expert opinions on whether the proof is valid.

> **Definition. 1 (Continuoity).** Given topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if
> $f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_X$ for every open set $O\in\tau_Y$.
>
> **Definition. 2 (Measurablity).** Given measurable spaces $(X,\Sigma_X)$ and $(Y,\Sigma_Y)$, a function $f:X\to Y$ is measurable if
> $f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$ for every subset $A\in\Sigma_Y$.
>
> **Theorem.** Let $\Sigma_i$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the topology $\tau_i$ on the space $i$ for $i=X,Y$. A function $f:X\to
> Y$ is continuous if and only if it is Borel measurable.
>
> *Proof.* Assume that $f$ is Borel measurable. Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebras contain all open subsets, $f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$ for
> every subset $A\in\Sigma_Y$ implies that $f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_X$ for
> every open set $O\in\tau_Y$.
>
> To show the converse, we usethe following proposition (see e.g.
> Proposition 2.4 in [here](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Markov.pdf)).
>
> **Proposition.** Suppose that $f^{-1}(O)\in\Sigma_X$ for every open set $O\in\tau_Y$. Then,  $f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$ for every subset
> $A\in\Sigma_Y$.
>
> Now assume that $f$ is continuous. Then, $\forall O\in\tau_Y, \,
> f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_X \Rightarrow f^{-1}(O)\in\Sigma_X \,
> \overset{Prop.}{\Rightarrow} \, \forall A\in\Sigma_Y, \,
> f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$. QED.

Comment: $f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$ for
> every subset $A\in\Sigma_Y$ implies that $f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_X$ for
> every open set $O\in\tau_Y$? How come?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're right. If $A$ is open, there is no reason for $f^{-1}(A)$ to be open.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$, then the function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\ 0&\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$ is Borel and discontinuous.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. If A is open, there is no reason for f−1(A) to be open.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely false. Continuity is much stronger than measurability. For example, consider the indicator function $f= \chi_{[0,1]}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which is measurable but non-continuous.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. If A is open, there is no reason for f−1(A) to be open.

Comment: But it's correct in one way, right? I.e., as per the second part of the proof, continuity implies Borel measurability?

Comment: @Farid Shahandeh yes that's certainly true.